# byte count in the Modbus TCP PDU

Tags: modbus-tcp

I am writing a Modbus TCP Master to communicate with the Modbus TCP slaves.

I am having issue in figuring out the right format of the packet

This is the standard packet  format:

```
 | Tx ID | Proto ID | Length | Unit ID ***| FCode | Data |***
```

As we know, the FCode & Data forms the PDU of the comms.

But my Modbus TCP slave has one byte at the front for the number of bytes transmitted.
looks like this:

```
| Tx ID | Proto ID | Length | Unit ID ***| FCode | byte count | Data |***
```

My question is this in anyway violation of the Modbus TCP spec ?

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the function code. Different function codes have different pdu:s.

Write single register (0x06) has for instance no "byte count", but Write multiple registers  (0x010) has.

What function codes are being used?

Comment: I found out that this format is acceptable as per implementation guide. I figured out that , the Slave is using a Modbus RTU over TCP, and hence the extra field for bytecount

Comment: Ok, I see.Have you replaced the slave or updated your code to RTU so that everything is working now?

Comment: Since I was adding support for the slave and it is acceptable in the spec, I added the support for both Modbus TCP and Modbus RTU over TCP and it works ok now. Thanks for your inputs